# Why doesn't apt doesn't know that I have some applications already installed from sources?

Tags: apt

If I install something through source, and install it, when apt-get something else, apt-get can't find the app I installed through source as dependency, How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` only knows about software that you installed using the package manager, that is by using `apt-get`, `aptitude`, Software Center or similar programs.

You can use  [equivs-control](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/equivs-control.1.html)  and [equivs-build](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/equivs-build.1.html) (package `equivs`, not installed by default) to create "fake packages" to fulfil dependencies.

In general it's better to use the package manager if possible.